# SQL Server 2014 レスポンス不良

Tags: sql-server, windows, oracle, sql-server-2014, linked-server

#### Premises / What you want to achieve

With the server replacement, the version of SQL Server was upgraded.

At that time, an event occurred in which repetition worsened compared to the old environment. I am in trouble without improvement.

#### Problems and error messages that have occurred

Event①Response deteriorated in client-server system. Login etc. as a whole.

Event ②

Accessing a linked server configured with Oracle Provider for OLE DB deteriorates a simple select process of 30,000 records from a few seconds to two and a half minutes.

#### environment

"Old environment"

- Build on VMWare
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1
- SQL Server 2014 32-bit version (12.0.5000.0)
- Link server consists of Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle

"New environment"

- Build on VMWare
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- SQL Server 2014 64-bit version (12.0.5000.0)
- Link server consists of Oracle Provider for OLE DB

#### Things I tried

I thought it was related to the network, but I couldn't find any noticeable phenomena by monitoring the performance monitor.

The same applies to other CPUs, memories, disks, etc.

Also, if data is obtained from an external DB without using a linked server, it can be obtained in a normal time, so it is speculated that this is a SQL Server problem.

I would like you to teach me how to identify the cause.  Thank you

Comment: in your question tag is related to sqlserver while in your error "linked server configured with Oracle Provider for OLE DB". Is there any  oracle include?

Comment: thank you for your answer.  Oracle is included.